# Why does entering the char 'T' not return the total of the array?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, cs50

I'm a beginner and trying to use an array to calculate the total number of hours someone spent working on the CS50 course over a variable number of weeks. However when it prompts to enter the char T, the program ends and it doesn't calculate the total.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int weeks = get_int("Weeks taking CS50: ");

    int hours [weeks];
    for (int i=0; i < weeks; i++)
    {
        hours[i] = get_int("WK %i Number of hours: ",i);
    }
    char output;
    do
    {
        output = get_char("Enter T for total hours, A for average hours per week: ");
    } while (output != 'T' && output != 'A');

    int total =0;
    for (int i=0; i < weeks; i++)
    {
        total += hours [i];

        if (output == 'T')

        return total;
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the if statement first but then the total is incorrect - comes out to something like 21782. I'm assuming the issue is in the second for loop - I will eventually make it calculate the average too but first I would like the total to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never print the total. You `return total` - and you also do it inside the first iteration of the loop, meaning that `total` will be the same as `hours[0]`.

You need to `printf` the result and also move it *after* the loop:

```c
    // ...

    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < weeks; i++) {
        total += hours[i];
    }

    if(output == 'T')
        printf("Total: %d\n", total);
    else
        printf("Average: %d\n", total / weeks);
```

Answer (score 3):

In this for loop

```
for (int i=0; i < weeks; i++)
{
    total += hours [i];

    if (output == 'T')

    return total;
}
```

in the first iteration of the loop the program at once exits due to this if statement

```
    if (output == 'T')

    return total;
```

If you want to output the value of total then write for example

```
if ( output == 'T' )
{
    int total = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < weeks; i++ )
    {
        total += hours[i];
    }

    printf( "total = %d\n", total );
}
```

Pay attention to that you should declare variables in minimum scope where they are used.

Or if you want to append your code for the selection `'A'` then the code can look like

```
int total = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < weeks; i++ )
{
    total += hours[i];
}

if ( output == 'T' )
{
    printf( "total = %d\n", total );
}
else
{
    printf( "average = %d\n", total / weeks );
}
```